# How to run MLlib's word2vec in CBOW mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

My understanding is that word2vec can be ran in two modes:

- continuous bag-of-words (CBOW) (order of words does not matter)
- continuous skip-gram (order of words matters)

I would like to run the **CBOW** implementation from Spark's MLlib, but it is not clear to me from the documentation and their example how to do it. This is the example listed on their page.

From: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-feature-extraction.html#example

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{Word2Vec, Word2VecModel}

val input = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_lda_data.txt").map(line => line.split(" ").toSeq)

val word2vec = new Word2Vec()

val model = word2vec.fit(input)

val synonyms = model.findSynonyms("1", 5)

for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {
  println(s"$synonym $cosineSimilarity")
}
```

**My questions:**

- Which of the two modes does this example use?
- Do you know how I can run the model in the **CBOW** mode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like MLlib's currently only implements skip-gram.

Here is the open ticket/pull request for the skip-gram model: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20372